# Matte Background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, texture

I'm curios on how to make a colored background look like a finish matte texture? Like the picture below. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what makes it matte is the dark Inner Glow possible to make with a Layer Effect or a layer with a soft dark diffuse frame.

- Make a square selection around the object
- Between the *Background* and the *Object Layer*, create a new black *Fill Layer*
- Set the *Fill Layer* opacity to 12%, Multiply mode
- Click the *Fill Layer* Mask icon to activate it
- Select all and center vertical and horizontal
- Deselect
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustment** > **Invert**
- **Menu Filter** > **Blur** > **Gaussian Blur**

[image]

[image: watch]

[Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/DhiZ2ZUQSS4) from unsplash.com

Comment: Wow!! Could you please tell me the step by step process on how you make this one?

Comment: See the answer update

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I'd use to replicate such an image.

1. Grey filled background layer
2. Red filled shape layer with Bevel & Emboss layer effect
3. Vignette layer created using the gradient tool, to darken edges. Reduced opacity on the layer
4. Headphone render (preferably with transparent background)

Note: For the sake of this example and for speed, I simply used a headphone image with a white background, and the layer mode was set to Multiply.

The shadow on the the headphone render really completes the illusion of the headphones laying on a surface. If the render you use doesn't already include a shadow, then add one using the layer effects Drop Shadow.

[image]